# PostgreSQL triggers functions (e.g.: RI_Fkey_setnull_upd etc..)

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I am getting acquainted with PostgreSQL.
Trying to find information for trigger functions listed below:

```
RI_Fkey_cascade_del
RI_Fkey_cascade_upd
RI_Fkey_check_ins
RI_Fkey_check_upd
RI_Fkey_noaction_del
RI_Fkey_noaction_upd
RI_Fkey_restrict_del
RI_Fkey_restrict_upd
RI_Fkey_setdefault_del
RI_Fkey_setdefault_upd
RI_Fkey_setnull_del
RI_Fkey_setnull_upd
suppress_redundant_updates_trigger
trigger_in
tsvector_updates_trigger
tsvector_updates_trigger_column
unique_key_recheck
```

Google shows me only sources of PGSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`suppress_redundant_updates_trigger`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-trigger.html) and [`tsvector_update_trigger`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-textsearch.html) are in the documentation.

`trigger_in` is a placeholder function associated with the `TRIGGER` pseudotype, and is never actually called.

The rest are implementation details of foreign key and uniqueness constraints. You should find everything you need to know about these constraints in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html). You shouldn't need to know anything about the underlying triggers (and if you do, the only explanation you're likely to find is the source code itself).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I expected for that. That's strange, that some functions are absent in the original documentation. I tried to find most of those there (using `command+F`) but no results along almost 3k pages))) Thanks anyway!